# Addition of 2 columns based on previous column

Tags: python, awk, sed

I have a tab separated file with 4 columns. Column 2 and Column 3 has numbers.

[image]

I want to sum first column 3 entry with second column 2 entry and print in place of second column 2, then this result sum with second column 3 entry and print at second column 3 place and this result sum with third column 2 entry and print at third column 2 place, and so on. The expected result would be:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: Did you try anything about it? Also, you tagged your post with several languages, without even mentionning them. I guess you expect a code from one of them, but people will help you if they can see that you tried something yourself.

Comment: I am sorry I am not a coder. Posted this question because was struggling with this. I will be grateful if you could help.

Comment: Do your files look exactly like that? i.e. space padded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't ask for Tcl code, but here's one way to do it. It could be prettier, but it works.

```
set data {
A1  1   2   a1
B1  3   4   b1
C1  5   6   c1
}

set ns {}
foreach {- a b -} $data {
    lappend ns $a $b
}

set a 0
set xs 1
foreach n [lrange $ns 1 end] {
    lappend xs [incr a $n]
}

foreach {a b} $xs r {a b c} {
    puts "[string toupper $r]1\t$a\t$b\t${r}1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following Python solution should work:

```
import csv

def convert(row):
    for col in [1, 2]:
        row[col] = int(row[col])
    return row

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:  
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')

    last = convert(next(csv_input))
    csv_output.writerow(last)

    for cols in csv_input:
        cols = convert(cols)
        cols[1] = cols[1] + last[2]
        cols[2] = cols[1] + cols[2]
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
        last = cols
```

Giving you an `output.csv` file as follows:

```
A1  1   2   a1
B1  5   9   b1
C1  14  20  c1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. It is working.... :) I am sure this will help me leaning Python.